# callback is not a function in mongoDB nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to validate if an email or username already exist in my mongoDB users collection in nodejs in my User Model.

But whenever i try to do that i get this error `callback is not a function`, when it finds that a username already exists in the next process that i am pushing to my processes array. meaning that the first process gets executed normally and there are no errors, but if an email doesnt already exists it goes to the next process and the error happens.

What am i doing wrong? How can I validate more than one field and return a response for that specific error?

here is my code :

```
register(params) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var processes = [];

      //check if the email is already registered
      let user = new models.User()
      processes.push((callback) => {
        user.emailExists(params.email,null).then((response) => {
          if(response && response.length) {
            callback({errorCode: 403, msg: 'User Already Exists.'});
          } else {

            db.collection("Users").insertOne(options, function (error, response) {

              if (error) {
                callback(error)
              } else {
                console.log(response.ops[0])
                if(response.ops[0]) {
                  callback(null, {result: response.ops[0]});
                } else {
                  callback({errorCode: 403, msg: 'User sign-up failed.'})
                }
              }
            })

          }
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });

      processes.push((callback) => {
        user.usernameExists(params.username).then((response) => {
          if(response && response.length) {
            callback({errorCode: 403, msg: 'username Already Exists.'});
          } else {

            db.collection("Users").insertOne(options, function (error, response) {

              if (error) {
                callback(error) //this is line 91
              } else {
                console.log(response.ops[0])
                if(response.ops[0]) {
                  callback(null, {result: response.ops[0]});
                } else {
                  callback({errorCode: 403, msg: 'User sign-up failed.'})
                }
              }
            })

          }
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });




      async.waterfall(processes, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      })
    })
  }

  emailExists(email, password) {
    // check that required params are set
    if (!email) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("Parameters not set")
        reject({errorCode: 403, msg: 'invalid.'});
      });
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      db.collection("Users").find({
        "email": email.toLowerCase()
      }).limit(1).toArray(function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          if (response && response.length) {
            if (!password) {
              resolve(response);
            } else {
              bcrypt.compare(password, response[0].password, function (err, success) {
                if (err) {
                  reject(err);
                } else {
                  if (success) {
                    resolve(true);
                  } else {
                    resolve(false);
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          } else {
            resolve(false);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  usernameExists(params) {
    if (!params ||  params.username) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("params not set");
        reject({errorCode: 403, msg: 'Invalid.'});
      });
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      db.collection("Users").find({
        "username": params.username
      }).limit(1).toArray(function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          if (response && response.length) {
            resolve(true)

          } else {
            resolve(false);
          }
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

error log:

[image]

Comment: can you post the error log ? that will help to debug the issue faster.

Comment: @Saroj Please find my edited question

Comment: it says the issue is User.js line# 91.  it is hard to check which line is line#91. could you provide more information ?

Comment: @Saroj i pointed out where line 91 is

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong in the code that it's hard to point to something specific tbh.

Please read how to use [waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#waterfall):

> An array of async functions to run. Each function should complete with any number of result values. The result values will be passed as arguments, in order, to the next task.

It means when you call

```
callback(null, {result: response.ops[0]});
```

the next `process` is being called with 2 arguments:

```
process({result: response.ops[0]}, callback)
```

you define your processes with only 1 argument, the rest are ignored. The first one is a json, so you get the error that it is not a function when you try to invoke it.

Now, how to fix it. Don't use waterfall. You don't need it. Bare async/await is more than enough and will make code much more readable.